# Dynamic Query with Order By clause arises an error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, sql-order-by

I have a dynamic query to execute. To this query, I receive some parameters from user (for example parameters for paging). So I use `sp_executesql` to execute the query. When I specify `order by` inside the query, I got an error message says ***The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.***. How can I over come the issue

---

`SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CaseID)AS RowNumber
            ,*

            FROM [dbo].[CV_CaseMaster]
            WHERE SpaceID =  @SID

            order by @OrderBy
            )
        AS CV_CaseMasterDetails WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @MinRow AND @MaxRow'`

`

---

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@SID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@MinRow int, @MaxRow int,@OrderBy VARCHAR(50)'
                  ,@SID=@SpaceID,@MinRow = @CurrentMinRow,@MaxRow = @CurrentMaxRow, @OrderBy =  @SortBy`
```

**OR**

Can I specify an `Order By` column with `sp_executesql` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put order by in the wrong position in the query and you can not use a parameter for order by.

I guess this will work but it leaves you open for SQL injection.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CaseID) AS RowNumber ,*
                  FROM [dbo].[CV_CaseMaster] 
                  WHERE SpaceID = @SID ) AS CV_CaseMasterDetails 
            WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @MinRow AND @MaxRow 
            ORDER BY '+@SortBy
```

Comment: This should work. What error are you getting now. You need to declare AND set SortBy above the query and remove the OrderBy from the executesql command

Comment: @Rauf - What error do you get? What value do you have in `@SortBy`?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Ohkie, It is WORKING now :)

Comment: why 2 different sort: `ORDER BY CaseID` and `ORDER BY '+@SortBy`?

Comment: @Jaider the first is used to generate a row number used for paging, the second is used to order the rows in the result set returned to the client.